# Download a sub stream with youtube_explode_dart

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, youtube, stream

I'm developing a Flutter app, using the package [youtube_explode_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_explode_dart).
Currently I download all the audio stream, then crop it using [ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg). Quickly this looks like :

```dart
var id = "aboZctrHfK8";
var file = File("mySong.mp4");
var start = "2000ms";
var end = "5000ms";

// Downloading audio only
var manifest = await yt.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(id);
var audio = manifest.audioOnly.first;
var audioStream = yt.videos.streamsClient.get(audio);
var output = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
for (final data in audioStream) {
    output.add(data);
}

// Croping audio
FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg = new FlutterFFmpeg();
await _flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments([
      "-v", "error",
      "-ss", start,
      "-to", end,
      "-i", file.path,
      "-acodec", "copy", "myCroppedSong.mp4"]);
```

Now I'm facing another issue: Some videos are really heavy and take a while to download. This is not acceptable for my end users, especially since I only want part of the original audio.

**Is there a way to download only a subset of the audio stream?**

Something like:

```dart
for (final data in audioStream.subset(start, end)) {
    output.add(data);
}
```

It would be anwsome!

Comment: Did you found some solutions or workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:youtube_explode_dart/youtube_explode_dart.dart';

// Initialize the YoutubeExplode instance.
final yt = YoutubeExplode();

Future<void> ExplodeDown() async {
  stdout.writeln('Type the video id or url: ');

  var url = stdin.readLineSync()!.trim();

  // Save the video to the download directory.
  Directory('downloads').createSync();

  // Download the video.
  await download(url);

  yt.close();
  exit(0);
}

Future<void> download(String id) async {
  // Get video metadata.
  var video = await yt.videos.get(id);

  // Get the video manifest.
  var manifest = await yt.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(id);
  var streams = manifest.videoOnly;

  // Get the audio track with the highest bitrate.
  var audio = streams.first;
  var audioStream = yt.videos.streamsClient.get(audio);

  // Compose the file name removing the unallowed characters in windows.
  var fileName = '${video.title}.${audio.container.name}'
      .replaceAll(r'\', '')
      .replaceAll('/', '')
      .replaceAll('*', '')
      .replaceAll('?', '')
      .replaceAll('"', '')
      .replaceAll('<', '')
      .replaceAll('>', '')
      .replaceAll('|', '');
  var file = File('downloads/$fileName');

  // Delete the file if exists.
  if (file.existsSync()) {
    file.deleteSync();
  }

  // Open the file in writeAppend.
  var output = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);

  // Track the file download status.
  var len = audio.size.totalBytes;
  var count = 0;

  // Create the message and set the cursor position.
  var msg = 'Downloading ${video.title}.${audio.container.name}';
  stdout.writeln(msg);

  // Listen for data received.
  //  var progressBar = ProgressBar();
  await for (final data in audioStream) {
    // Keep track of the current downloaded data.
    count += data.length;

    // Calculate the current progress.
    var progress = ((count / len) * 100).ceil();
    print (progress);

    // Update the progressbar.
    // progressBar.update(progress);

    // Write to file.
    output.add(data);
  }
  await output.close();
}
```

> ```
>   **How to download load youtube video & audio & play stream audio **
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
String youTubeLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ja-85lFDSEM";
Future<void> _downloadVideo(youTubeLink) async{
final yt = YoutubeExplode();
final video = await yt.videos.get(youTubeLink);
// Get the video manifest.
final manifest = await yt.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(youTubeLink);
final streams = manifest.muxed;
final audio = streams.first;
final audioStream = yt.videos.streamsClient.get(audio);
final fileName = '${video.title}.${audio.container.name.toString()}'
    .replaceAll(r'\', '')
    .replaceAll('/', '')
    .replaceAll('*', '')
    .replaceAll('?', '')
    .replaceAll('"', '')
    .replaceAll('<', '')
    .replaceAll('>', '')
    .replaceAll('|', '');

final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final path = dir.path;
final directory = Directory('$path/video/');
await directory.create(recursive: true);
final file = File('$path/video/$fileName');
final output = file.openWrite(mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
var len = audio.size.totalBytes;
var count = 0;
var msg = 'Downloading ${video.title}.${audio.container.name}';
stdout.writeln(msg);
await for (final data in audioStream){
  count += data.length;
  var progress = ((count / len) * 100).ceil();
  print(progress);
  output.add(data);
}
await output.flush();
await output.close();
```

}

Comment: onPressed: () {  downloadVideo(youTubeLink);  }

Comment: do not download work on click to download